# Payment declined to update my billing details in iTunes Store

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I'm trying to add my debt master card to my billing details and it says 'payment declined'. I had a chat with the Apple support and they asked me to check with the bank. I did that and the bank said the card was fine. I've been using the same card for all the other payments online and its been working properly.

I've tried doing this from my iPhone 6 and my MacBook Air (Yosemite)

Does anyone know how to fix it as the people at Apple support don't know what's wrong?

P.S. I have read the other threads saying click 'done' but I need to subscribe to Apple Music.. hence i want to pay!

Comment: If Apple & your bank can't fix it, we can't.

Comment: Do you have an outstanding charge on your account, such as from an App, song, movie, etc. which had been purchased but the card later declined? Other things to try, sometimes if there is an old address, or try abbreviating the street name (Think 1st Ave instead of 1st Avenue, etc) or vice versa.

Comment: No. The Apple support team online even said that there was no  problem with my iTunes account. I do have a doubt that  we could only use Credit Cards. Still confused though.

Comment: @deep my debit card works fine with iTunes Store

Answer (score 1):

You financial institution most likely rejected the pre-authorisation, you have to contact the Fraud department of your financial institution (not a bank advisor) and ask to authorise the iTunes Store

You can also use another Credit card or even better, use an iTunes Gift Card instead.